# What are the solutions to access a client's subnet with an IP of its subnet?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

In order to connect two clients together, I have a **Central Gateway OpenVPN server**. Clients can't access each other directly due to firewall or 4G/LTE mobile or IPoE.

- The VPN network is `172.16.0.0/24`
- The VPN server shares its private LAN `192.168.111.0/24` to the **Client A** only.
- The VPN client **DEV(yellow)** shares its private LAN `192.168.164.0/24`.

  - Defined as **VPN gateway**
- The VPN client **Client A*** doesn't share anything, it's a pure client. (my computer)

The configuration works with *OpenVPN Access Server*. I'll try to port it to the *OpenVPN 2.5 community* version later.

Here is the diagram of the infrastructure
[image: infra_diagram]

The **DEV network's switch** is also connected to a different subnet `10.1.0.0/24` called **SERVER TESTING**.

The subnet/servers `10.1.0.0/24` must be accessed with the IP `10.50.0.10 gw:10.50.0.254`. I don't have any control over that network at all.

#### Questions

- Now, how can I setup the computer on **Client A** to be seen as `10.50.0.10`? As if the **Client A** computer was directly connected to the **DEV's switch**.

  - The red arrows are tunneled. The green arrows are clear/normal packets.

#### More info:

- I can create a new OpenVPN server if necessary. (bridge?TAP?)
- **Client A**'s computer has a single NIC connected to the switch.
- I have admin rights to all the servers/gateways but the grey **TESTING SERVER**

#### Thoughts

I thought using a 2nd NIC in my DEV client and bridging it could make it working without NAT.

Example:
[image]

The gateway is **192.168.101.2** and **192.168.101.3** can communicate with **.5** without NAT. But it seems I'm wrong.

Does that mean there is no way to have a transparent connection using a vpn?

Comment: If you dont have access to the networking equipment of the Server subnet, you cant exchange routing information (be it static or via a protocol) so the only option for you is to use NAT. You need to have a device that you control to have access to the server network (1 interface of a router connected to the server network) and then you have to do a NAT rule to allow all your clients to access this network. I would suggest using a PAT rule to only use the one IP of the interface in the server network for all the clients in your network.

Comment: Let's say I can have a second NIC on the **DEV vpn client** connected to the switch. Would it make more sense to use a tap/bridged vpn tunnel and set the 2nd NIC as the bridge device? In that case, no NAT, no PAT, just straight untouched frames. I only need a **single** client to access the SERVER subnet.

Comment: (updated) Thank you, I can set `10.50.0.10` as a 2nd IP of **DEV vpn gateway client** and use a static NAT. The PAT shouldn't be necessary since only one client needs to access the SERVER subnet.

Comment: A Bridge mode does not replace IP adresses. So you would be able to bring the traffic from your clients to the Server Testing network, but the devices in the SERVER TESTING network wont be able to answer because they dont know where these IP addresses are coming from. So you really need a NAT in order for the SERVERS to respons to that IP they know (becuase it is part of their network) and the device that performas NAT will then translate the IP back to the original client.

Comment: I'm missing something. There is no way of doing a transparent bridge with a vpn? Using NAT requires my client/app to use a vpn network IP as a source IP. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: So you are talking about a Layer2 VPN. OpenVPN calls it Bridging. Yes, this would work, but you have to use the same subnet on both sides, as you correctly did in your drawing. You bring together the network at Layer2. So you would have to consider things like spanning-tree topology. based on the network design, it could be that the network will converge based on the priority of the root bridge (lowest mac). I wouldnt just do that without knowing the other side of the network. Maybe inform the admins of the other network what you want to achieve to find a solution together.